# Correct way to parse JSON payload with multiple root objects

Tags: ios

I'm using AFNetworking for my network requests. Assume that I have the following JSON payload:

```
{
    "car": [{
         "name": "Blue BMW",
         "owner_id": "123"
    }],
    "owners": [{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "John"
    }]
}
```

What is the correct way to parse that JSON structure considering that the object graph is not persisted using CoreData. Iterating through the `owners` object to find the owner details for each car would be highly inefficient, so what is a better approach?

Comment: Rhetorical question: why is **everyone** looking for that magical "most efficient way"?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with that? Imagine the above structure with a few hundred objects and the problem would immediately become obvious.

Comment: You can sort the JSON and use binary search. But you know, the rule of optimization: don't optimize until you are sure that it is needed. Linear search may be "inefficient" in pure mathematical terms, but what's the point of optimizing if no human being can recognize the difference? By the way, if you do have hundreds of objects, the bottle neck will likely be the time required to transfer data from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Iterating through the owners object to find the owner details for each car would be highly inefficient, so what is a better approach?

`O(n^2)` is perfectly fine for reasonably small `n`. On a modern iOS device, you'd have to get into an order of 10k objects for this to even see a performance hit—likely much smaller than what you're being sent back by JSON.

As others mentioned before in comments, and as the [old saying goes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize), "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Just code it. If your app is slow, profile it in instruments. Only then can you really know what the bottlenecks in your application are (humans are generally very bad at guessing *a priori*)

Answer (score -1):

Use `NSJSONSerialization` class to parse JSON.
Use `+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error`
to create  a Foundation object from given JSON data.

Comment: Because it doesn't answer my question. I looking for the correct way to parse objects with relationships across multiple root objects.